# How to float table in landscape environment

Tags: tables, floats, landscape

I have a wide table, so I put it into the `landscape` environment. Unfortunately, the float does not work any more. The new page in `landscape` begins exactly where I included it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}                 % English language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % German characters etc.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % German characters etc.
\usepackage{apacite}                        % For the bibliographystyle
\usepackage{bibgerm}                        % Stylepackage
\usepackage{enumerate}                      % For enumerations
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % For figures
\usepackage{caption}                        % For graphicx-cations
\usepackage{subcaption}                     % For graphicx-subcations
\usepackage{setspace}                       % For line spacing
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=35mm,right=35mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}                      % For horizontal format
\usepackage{tabularx}                       % For tables
\usepackage{multirow}                       % For multiple rows in table
\usepackage{float}                          % Prevents moving images with [H] 
\usepackage{acronym}                        % For abbreviations 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}                          % For coloured texts 

\begin{document}

Text, text ...

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
    \caption{Example}
\begin{tabular}{l||ccccc|c|c}
    \hline
      & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text \\
    \hline
    Text & 5 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & \\
    Text & 1 & 0 & 3 & - & 2 & 5 & 5 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

Text, text ...

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please complete your code `\documentclass....\end{document}`

Comment: a float will go where latex wants to put it; it is independent of the landscape'd page.  what would work better is to put the contents of the table, *within the float*, into a minipage and use `\rotate` from the `graphicx` package to turn it sideways.  alternatively, get rid of the `table` float and simply set the `tabular` within the `landxcape` environment; for this, you will have to set the caption with `\captionof` from the `capt-of` package.

Comment: Thanks. I chose the suggestion by Harish Kumar. It seems smoother and easyer just to use:

\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{...} 
   Text
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sidewaystable` from `rotating` package. Just change `table` to `sidewaystable` and get rid of `landscape` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1]
\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\centering
    \caption{Example}
\begin{tabular}{l||ccccc|c|c}
    \hline
      & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text & Text \\
    \hline
    Text & 5 & 4 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & \\
    Text & 1 & 0 & 3 & - & 2 & 5 & 5 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems smooth. The table is sideways, yes. But from that table on, all of them were moved to the very end. Furthermore, 2 pages of Latin text were included... WTF?! :-)

Comment: @ChristianFu include  p in the optional argument (or probably better do not use the `[ht]` option at all), it's main effect is to make going to end of document more likely.