# How to wrap text around landscape page with table and caption

Tags: tables, floats, landscape

My question is related to [How to wrap text around landscape page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11471/how-to-wrap-text-around-landscape-page). Contrary to explanation and solution there, my goal is to have a table in landscape with a caption that is located on top of it vertically on the left. I have learnt about two ways to specify a landscape page. The solution advocated in the above thread is to use `\rotatebox{90}` in conjunction with a `[p]` float specified for the figure. This works also with `table`. However, when I add a `caption` the caption is located on top of the table in horizontal direction (not rotated). The text float (wrap) around the table is fine. The code I use is basically

```
\begin{table}  [p]
  \caption{This is the table caption}
  \rotatebox{90}{
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}
      ...
     \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}
```

An alternative is to use package `pdflandscape`. The code now becomes

```
\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}  [p]
    \caption{This is the table caption}
    \centering
      \begin{tabular}
       ...
      \end{tabular}
    }
  \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

The caption is nicely above the table (vertically on the left), but now the text does not float around the table anymore. How do I get both, the float and the caption vertically on the left?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212839/134144 (Also rotating the caption if one uses `rotatebox`) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260558/134144 (Regarding the usage of `sidewaystable` to rotate caption and table).

Comment: @leandriis Great, the first link presents a workable hack.

Comment: @leandriis Okay sidewaystable is even better.